# Access ViewModel integer list with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on ASP.Net MVC Core application and I have a view model with a list of integers:

```
  public List<int?> SelectedIds { get; set; } = new List<int?>();
```

Now I want to access this property via javascript in order:

```
@model Project.ViewModels.Test.MyViewModel

  $(function() {
                 var test = @Model.SelectedIds;
   });
```

But in the Chrome console this is throwing an error:

```
 var test = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@model Project.ViewModels.Test.MyViewModel

  $(function() {
                 var test = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.SelectedIds));
   });
```

Comment: For some reason I cannot use Encode, it says  Cannot resolve symbol 'Encode', do I need to import something?

Comment: try `Json.Serialize`